# Font Face does not work in IE 7,8

Tags: css, font-face

I've a problem with @font-face. In ie7 and ie8 it does not work. In 9 and all other browsers it works.

My code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KSD-Avenir-Roman';
    src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Roman.eot');
    src: local('?'), url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Roman.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Roman.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Roman.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'KSD-Avenir-Black';
    src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Black.eot');
    src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Black.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Black.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Black.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'KSD-Avenir-Light';
    src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Light.svg#open_sans_condensedbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Can someone fix me?

Thank you!

Comment: have you got a licensed .eot version of this font? IE may not embed a font without license

Comment: Is it just the KSD-Avenir-Roman font that is not working?  I ask because I don't know what this means "src: local('?')"

Comment: I fixed it! The font was generated wrong. With another generator it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but maybe:

```
src: local('?')
```

should be

```
src: url('fonts/KSD-Avenir-Roman.eot?#iefix')
```

Comment: Great.  I have always used www.fontsquirrel.com/ for generating, so far so good.